# Call to undefined method Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader::setPsr4()

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I have a project that have multiple subfolders. In one of the folders they are some "addons". All of these addons have a composer.json and a vendor-folder. I now wanted to build my own addon and created a new folder and put a `composer.json` into that directory. `composer install` works without any problems, but when I'm somehow installing my addon I'm getting the error

```
FastCGI: server "/fcgi-bin-php5-fpm-ezi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader::setPsr4()
```

What could cause this problem? I already did `composer dump-autoload` and `composer global update`, because I found these solutions on the internet, but it still doesn't work. Do I have to do something special to make it work in sub-folders?

This is currently my composer.json

```
{
  "name": "namespace/projectname-addonname",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "namespace1\\namespace2\\namespace3\\" : "src"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if that helps, but when I `var_dump` the loader this is the result

```
object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader)#138 (4) {
  ["prefixes":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fallbackDirs":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["useIncludePath":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["classMap":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

After that the `$loader->setPsr4` method is called and I'm getting the fatal error.

The strange thing is, that when using `classmap` instead of `psr-4` for autoloading, it works without any problems.

Comment: What's your composer version? What's the result of `composer --version` ?

Comment: I have `Composer version 1.0-dev (6eb50623e6e00bac4ed893802836e50b62c83434) 2016-02-08 19:03:10` and same problem

Answer (score 2):

```
"autoload":
 {
    "psr-4":
    {
    "namespace1\\namespace2\\namespace3\\" : "src"
    },

    "classmap": ["src/"]
}
```

Try this!

Answer (score 2):

In my case was problem with multiple version of `ClassLoader.php` file in code. Let me explain my case, I have multiple Wordpress plugins with Composer inside and how they are initialized first of them require `ClassLoader.php` with follow code in `composer/autoload_real.php` file

```
if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
  require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
}
```

Then when you call again `require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';` class is already loaded and may have different interface (missing functions in our case).

You can check it with Reflection, add follow code to `composer/autoload_real.php` right after `new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();`

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('\\Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader');
die($reflector->getFileName());
```

**In my case was Class loaded from different source then current working dir.**

**Solution**:

- download latest version of composer with `composer self-update`
- then visit all folders with `composer.json` in your project and call `composer update`
- then run `composer global update` and check if that's help